# iOS. Push Notification custom sound doesn't play full length when the app is in foreground

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

In my app I'm playing custom sounds for the push notifications. In the push payload the sound is defined like this : `sound = "push_sound.wav";` and I store the sound file inside the `Library/Sounds` folder. And everything is fine except the fact that when a notification is received while the app is in foreground the sound playing occasionally gets cut. It doesn't play full length (3 seconds), it plays just for approximately one second. I tried using all the formats: `wav`, `caf`, `aiff` but nothing helps. Of course I can play the sound manually but this will be my last resort. I would like to figure out what's wrong. Is it a bug of the system or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The sound gets cut when you remove the banner ? When the iphone is unlocked, notification sound is playing until the notification banner disappear.

Comment: @GabrielDiez Do you find any solution for this? I have the same problem as mentioned above. 30 seconds custom ringtone got cut off when banner was removed.